# Limiting number of instances of executables called by a for loop

Tags: vba, excel

I have a program that exports text files which which are then used by an executable to run simulations which take generally 5 to 10 minutes each.

I have created a for loop which runs this process `For Each` text file. I originally wrote code for a separate executable, which the VBA macro would call, and this would run each simulation in series. I wanted to be able to run more in parallel, so I transferred the macro directly to VBA, but this causes every simulation to run simultaneously and brings the processor to a crawl.

Is there a way to allow for a limited number of simulations to run at one time?

EDIT: Sorry, I wrote this using a phone, because my computer was bogged down with this exact problem at the time. Here is the code. I have a function for running one simulation which moves the required exe (same for every simulation) and input.txt file into its own subfolder, and a second function which runs the first function on a loop over listbox selections:

```
Function RunSimulations() As Boolean
    For k = 0 To myListBox.ListCount - 1
        If myListBox.Selected(k) = True Then
               SimulateOne(myListBox.List(k))
            End If
        End If
    Next k
End Function

Function SimulateOne(inputFName As String) As Boolean
    Dim currPath As String, inptPath As String, simsPath As String
    Dim destPath As String, origFile As String, destFile As String

    'Defines various folder paths
    currPath = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\"
    inptPath = currPath & INPUT_FOLDERNAME & "\"
    simsPath = currPath & SIMS_FOLDERNAME & "\"
        If Len(Dir(simsPath, vbDirectory)) = 0 Then MkDir simsPath
    destPath = simsPath & Replace(inputFName, ".txt", "") & "\"
        If Len(Dir(destPath, vbDirectory)) = 0 Then MkDir destPath

    'Move input files from "input_files" to subfolders within "simulations"
    origFile = inptPath & inputFName
    destFile = destPath & INPUT_FILENAME  'Changes name to "INPUT.TXT"
    If Len(Dir(destFile)) <> 0 Then SetAttr destFile, vbNormal: Kill destFile
    If Len(Dir(origFile)) <> 0 Then
        FileCopy origFile, destFile
    Else
        SimulateOne = False
        Exit Function
    End If

    If Len(Dir(currPath & EXE_FILENAME)) <> 0 Then
        'Moves exe files to new subfolder within "simulations"
        FileCopy currPath & EXE_FILENAME, destPath & EXE_FILENAME

        'Run exe
        ChDrive Left(destPath, 1)
        ChDir destPath
        Shell (destPath & EXE_FILENAME)
        SimulateOne = True
    Else
        SimulateOne = False
        Exit Function
    End If

End Function
```

EDIT: Implemented this loop recently. Wondering about the efficiency (or lack thereof) of the loop that goes constantly until the processor count drops low enough.

```
For k = 0 To myListBox.ListCount - 1
    Do While ProcessRunningCount(EXE_FILENAME) >= processLimit
        Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:05"))
    Loop
    If myListBox.Selected(k) = True Then  runResult = SimulateOne(myListBox.List(k))
Next k
```

Comment: re: *'... this causes every simulation to run simultaneously ...'* - I'd like to see that please.

Comment: Seconded -  please show your actual code.  Does the executable quit when it's done processing the file?  If Yes you could use WMI to count how many instances are running and launch a new one when the count drops below your threshold.  Do that in a loop using `OnTime`  http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/478621/VBScript-Count-Instances-of-a-Process

Comment: Look at creating a batch file and shelling that out.  In the batch file `call` the exe. As in `Call c:\temp\some.exe File1AsArgument` the next line `Call c:\temp\some.exe File2AsArgument`  The `call` instruction will cause the command line to wait for the current process to finish before the next call is sent.

Comment: @MatthewD I wanted to eliminate the need to include multiple files in a subfolder to run a simulation (this will be used by others, so I want it to be a simple set up). Do you mean having another exe file alongside the rest to run each?

Comment: No. I mean write all the files you want to process to a batch file. One file per line.  Then shell out the .bat file. That will execute them one at a time.

Comment: @MatthewD OK so something like call [exe] [txt1], call [exe] [txt2] etc.? In that case, how would I set it to run maybe say 5 at a time?

Comment: @TimWilliams are the `Set objWMIService` and `Set colProcess` both usable as is? Also, if I'm using 64-bit, is it ("Select * from x64_Process") or something? Or still 32 bit for this?

Comment: Most of the VBscript WMI examples will translate directly to VBA.  I don't know the answer to your 64-bit question.  64 bit OS, Excel, and/or exe ?  I would just try it out and see what you get.

Comment: @TimWilliams when I run it, I get "Run-time error '424': Object required" because of `WScript.Echo "There are currently " & "(" & instances & ") " & """" & processName & """" & " Instances running!"`. Is this because I am using VBA rather than VB? How can I correct this?

Comment: Since you're using VBA you can use `Msgbox`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT**:  OK here is a tested implementation of the sort of thing you want to do.  I'm using a simple vbscript to simulate your exe (so I'm monitoring "wscript.exe")

```
Dim colFiles As Collection 'has items to be processed

'sets up the items to be processed and kicks off the runs
Sub InitSimulations()
    Dim x As Long, arr(1 To 20) As String
    Set colFiles = New Collection
    For x = 1 To 20
        colFiles.Add "File_" & x
    Next x
    RunSimulations
End Sub

'Initially called by InitSimulations, then calls itself periodically 
'    to check whether a new run needs to be started
Sub RunSimulations()
    Const MAX_PROCESSES As Long = 5
    Dim sFile As String

    'below our threshold?
    If HowMany("wscript.exe") < MAX_PROCESSES Then
        'any left to process?
        If colFiles.Count > 0 Then
            sFile = colFiles(1)
            colFiles.Remove 1
            SimulateOne sFile
            Debug.Print Now, "Kicked off " & sFile
        End If
    End If

    'Calls itself again in one second if any still remaining to process
    '  if your processes are long-running then can adjust for longer delay
    If colFiles.Count > 0 Then
        Application.OnTime Now + TimeSerial(0, 0, 1), "RunSimulations", , True
    End If

End Sub

'Launch a simulation process
Sub SimulateOne(FileName)
    Shell "wscript.exe ""C:\_Stuff\Test.vbs"""
    'not doing anything with FileName...
    'test vbs has one line:  WScript.Sleep 10000
End Sub

'Count how many "procName" processes are running
Function HowMany(procName As String) As Long
    Dim objWMIService, colProcess, processName
    Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\.\root\cimv2")
    Set colProcess = objWMIService.ExecQuery _
    ("Select * from Win32_Process where Name = '" & procName & "'")
    HowMany = colProcess.Count
End Function
```

Comment: this function worked great for counting processes, thanks! Now I'm finding using Application.Wait("00:00:10") is causing it to pause forever, because I think it's looping through them all at once and pausing the application for a long time, is that possible?

Comment: That looks really great. I did not know you could call a function from within itself. Meanwhile I had got things working using a function that loops while monitoring the number of processes running (see edit to my question). Although I imagine my method costs more in processing power, or maybe not? What is the difference in efficiency?

Comment: I think Wait uses the processor more than OnTime: I don't know if that would make a significant difference though.

Answer (score 1):

Could the answer be as simple as waiting a certain amount of time in your loop. That could control the number of processes to some degree.  This will kick one off, wait five minutes, kick off the next, wait five minutes, kick off the next etc..

```
Function RunSimulations() As Boolean
    For k = 0 To myListBox.ListCount - 1
        If myListBox.Selected(k) = True Then
            SimulateOne(myListBox.List(k))
            Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:05:00"))
        End If
    Next k
End Function
```

If that isn't good enough I have some VBA functions that can be used.

```
'API Calls - place these at the top of your code with your globals
Private Declare Function OpenProcess Lib "kernel32" ( _
    ByVal dwDesiredAccess As Long, ByVal bInheritHandle As Long, ByVal dwProcessId As Long) As Long
Private Declare Function CloseHandle Lib "kernel32" ( _
    ByVal hObject As Long) As Long
Private Declare Function EnumProcesses Lib "PSAPI.DLL" ( _
    lpidProcess As Long, ByVal cb As Long, cbNeeded As Long) As Long
Private Declare Function EnumProcessModules Lib "PSAPI.DLL" ( _
    ByVal hProcess As Long, lphModule As Long, ByVal cb As Long, lpcbNeeded As Long) As Long
Private Declare Function GetModuleBaseName Lib "PSAPI.DLL" Alias "GetModuleBaseNameA" ( _
    ByVal hProcess As Long, ByVal hModule As Long, ByVal lpFileName As String, ByVal nSize As Long) As Long
Private Const PROCESS_VM_READ = &H10
Private Const PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION = &H400
```

Just feed the proc name b = IsProcessRunning("ProcName.exe")

```
Private Function IsProcessRunning(ByVal sProcess As String) As Boolean
'Check to see if a process is currently running
Const MAX_PATH      As Long = 260
Dim lProcesses()    As Long
Dim lModules()      As Long
Dim N               As Long
Dim lRet            As Long
Dim hProcess        As Long
Dim sName           As String

sProcess = UCase$(sProcess)
ReDim lProcesses(1023) As Long

If EnumProcesses(lProcesses(0), 1024 * 4, lRet) Then
    For N = 0 To (lRet \ 4) - 1
        hProcess = OpenProcess(PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION Or PROCESS_VM_READ, 0, lProcesses(N))
        If hProcess Then
            ReDim lModules(1023)
            If EnumProcessModules(hProcess, lModules(0), 1024 * 4, lRet) Then
                sName = String$(MAX_PATH, vbNullChar)
                GetModuleBaseName hProcess, lModules(0), sName, MAX_PATH
                sName = Left$(sName, InStr(sName, vbNullChar) - 1)
                If sProcess = UCase$(sName) Then
                    IsProcessRunning = True
                    Exit Function
                End If
            End If
        End If
        CloseHandle hProcess
    Next N
End If
End Function
```

You probably want this one. It will return the number of time it finds the process. If it is more than you want running. Don't kick off another.

```
Private Function ProcessRunningCount(ByVal sProcess As String) As Long
'Check to see if how many occurences of a process are currently running
Const MAX_PATH      As Long = 260
Dim lProcesses()    As Long
Dim lModules()      As Long
Dim N               As Long
Dim lRet            As Long
Dim hProcess        As Long
Dim sName           As String
Dim lCount          As Long

    sProcess = UCase$(sProcess)
    ReDim lProcesses(1023) As Long
    lCount = 0

    If EnumProcesses(lProcesses(0), 1024 * 4, lRet) Then
        For N = 0 To (lRet \ 4) - 1
            hProcess = OpenProcess(PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION Or PROCESS_VM_READ, 0, lProcesses(N))
            If hProcess Then
                ReDim lModules(1023)
                If EnumProcessModules(hProcess, lModules(0), 1024 * 4, lRet) Then
                    sName = String$(MAX_PATH, vbNullChar)
                    GetModuleBaseName hProcess, lModules(0), sName, MAX_PATH
                    sName = Left$(sName, InStr(sName, vbNullChar) - 1)
                    If sProcess = UCase$(sName) Then
                        lCount = lCount + 1
                    End If
                End If
            End If
            CloseHandle hProcess
        Next N
    End If
    ProcessRunningCount = lCount

End Function
```

Something like this

```
Function RunSimulations() As Boolean
    For k = 0 To myListBox.ListCount - 1

        Do While ProcessRunningCount("chrome.exe") >= 5 'Enter you proc name here
            Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:10"))
        Loop

        If myListBox.Selected(k) = True Then
            SimulateOne(myListBox.List(k))
        End If
    Next k
End Function
```

Comment: Thanks, this is awesome. I like the simplicity of the Do While loop here. I wonder, does it require more CPU just to leave the loop as `Do While ProcCount("myproc.exe") >= 5 Loop` rather than having a .Wait in there? It seems to me that .Wait requires the CPU to check the time constantly anyway, or am I wrong?

Comment: @teepee I do read sleep does not require CPU cycles while Wait does. But have not verified that.
`Private Declare Sub Sleep Lib "kernel32" (ByVal dwMilliseconds As Long)`
'following in your code in place of the Wait command:
`Sleep 5*1000*60`  'Sleep uses milliseconds so to convert into 5 minutes...

Comment: And there is seems to be some difference for 32 vs 64 bit systems but I haven't verified that either.  `#If VBA7 Then  
    Public Declare PtrSafe Sub Sleep Lib "kernel32" (ByVal dwMilliseconds As LongPtr) 'For 64 Bit Systems  
#Else  
    Public Declare Sub Sleep Lib "kernel32" (ByVal dwMilliseconds as Long) 'For 32 Bit Systems  
#End If`

Comment: Thanks, that's good to know. I did do a couple tests, and found if I use .wait within the loop, Excel's CPU usage jumps up to 25 during most of the process. If I leave the loop blank, essentially just allowing it to repeatedly check the number of simulations running, then its CPU usage remains 0. I wonder if sleep would help things even more, I'll try.